# Call mysql command in symfony2 controller

Tags: mysql, shell, symfony, command

I have a question regarding symfony2. How can I execute a mysql command in a controller? Something like an import. I tried with execute() but with no avail (also I don't get any errors): 
mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
   throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage

Answer (score 0):

To get pdo Object:  `$entityManager->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection()`...

But depreacated.

Otherwise, in doctrine you have a built-in SQL based language (DQL) to create SQL-like request and returns Entities... See the doc: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

If you want to do a shell command, I don't see why you try to do this...

Comment: My issue was a bit more complicated than this. I had to import  in a best case scenario 150000 rows in the database and I had  to do it while the user is waiting a response for this. I tried with doctrine, but it was taking too long. The mysql import was the fastest way I could find.

Comment: And what about read a .sql file and process it with a foreach loop? It takes too much time, also?

Comment: The sql file alone is 35Mb. The foreach would have 150000 loops. And this would be a good scenario. The mysql import was the solution for my problem.